# Иероглифы вместо заглавных букв в Notepad++

Tags: кодировка, notepad++

Редактирую PHP и HTML-файлы, используя FileZilla и Notepad++. В редакторе кириллица отображается нормально, но когда открываю файлы в браузере, начинаются глюки.

Например, слово **«Резерв»** после загрузки документа на сервер при просмотре в браузере выглядит так: **«ђезерв»**.

Когда я скачиваю файл на ПК и открываю его простым блокнотом, слово отображается так же, как и в браузере. Когда я заменяю иероглиф на нормальную букву Р (в простом блокноте), и перезаливаю файл, в браузере всё отображается нормально.

Может, кто-то сталкивался с подобным? Есть какое-то решение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Noterpad++ откройте ваш файл и установите кодировку UTF-8(без BOM)

Comment: а если у меня сайт весь на windows-1251? Переводить все файлы и базу в UTF-8?

Comment: Создайте файл с расширением htaccess напишите строчку AddDefaultCharset UTF-8Если Вам нужна windows-1251, то тогда так:AddDefaultCharset WINDOWS-1251